# Javascript not working on first click only after second click

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to get my javascript to work, but I have to click on submit button twice before it executes initially. After that it seems to work correctly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validation() {
    var home = document.forms["frmTest"]["phone-number"].value;
    var mobile = document.forms["frmTest"]["mobile-number"].value;
    var validPhone = true;
    var errorMessage = ""

    if (home == "" && mobile == "") {
        errorMessage = "You must fill in at least 1 phone number";
        validPhone = false;
    }
    if (validPhone) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("mobile-number").setCustomValidity(errorMessage);
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit1").click();
        //alert(errorMessage);
        return false;
    }

}
```

The HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin:0px; padding:0px " action="thankyou-test.php"
                      method="post"
                      name="frmTest"
                      id="frmTest"
                      onsubmit="return validation();"
                >
```

...

```
<tr>
                                <td width="50%"><input id="phone-number" placeholder="Phone Number"
                                                       name="phone-number"
                                                       maxlength="11" type="text" pattern="^(01|02|03)\d{8,9}"
                                                       title="UK Phone numbers must begin with 01, 02, 03 and be 10 or 11 characters in length"></td>
                                <td width="50%"><input id="mobile-number" placeholder="Mobile Number"
                                                       name="mobile-number" maxlength="11" type="text"
                                                       pattern="^(07)\d{8,9}"
                                                       title="UK Mobile numbers must begin with 07 and be 10 or 11 characters in length"></td>
                            </tr>
```

Please help! Everything works, except that I need to click twice initially.

Comment: Hi, could you add your html to the question. It also helps to  make a working example on a site like jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue you have. Cheers

Comment: Also add how you bind the form send to the function. Some style comments: 1) Add ";" after your statemens (`errorMessage = ""`) 2) compare with `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: Hi I have added my HTML code

Comment: also it appears my function is only executing once when its executed, but it is not doing any further additional checks when i click submit again. @MrGiggles